# 6 JDK options when installing netbeans IDE on Linux, which one must we select?

Tags: fedora, java, jdk, ide

**Notes**

- fedora 27 (KDE plasma 5).
- netbeans-8.2-javase-linux.sh

  ---

Hello pals,  I installed before on my system:

- java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel

One known path about this is`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk`.

what does those another JDK options means there?
I installed one openjdk (java) but there are more than one.

Which one is the correct java option?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we must select the last one
java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-5.b14.fc27.x86_64